# Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES) spring boot and MySql

Tags: java, docker, api

I created an api gateway using spring boot and I wanted to connect it to my local MySql DB.
I am getting two errors:

- Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)
- Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory

I don't think there is a problem with the password, I was able to connect with it to root in the mySql workbench. I also made sure that all column names in the code are corresponding to those in the tables.
**I will mention that I have a docker container up, and port 3306 is not accessible unless that container is running.**
Would appreciate any ideas that can solve those errors

---

```
server.port = 8080
spring.dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rest_api?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= = xxxxx
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: Note that the "snippet" button is only for CSS, HTML and JavaScript that can be run in a browser. For all other languages, use the `{}` button (or four-space indents, or a line with triple backticks and nothing else before and after) to add code samples.

Comment: BTW, notice how you have two `=`s on the password line? If the configuration parsing thinks there's an `=` and a space before your actual password, and those don't belong there... well, there you are.

Comment: `localhost` resolves to `172.17.0.1`, which hints for a bridged network. `docker network connect` and `inspect` may provide more details; the values in `my.cnf` need to match these.

Comment: The problem was the two ==